# 2 emoticons in object is not replaced correctly javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to replace emoticon codes with images. Most of the script is working fine. But I have some trouble with the emoticon codes `>:(` and `<3)`. The emoticon code `<3)` is not working at all, nothing gets replaced. And the emoticon code `>:(` gets replaced by the emoticon for the emoticon code `:(` and the `>` sign is left in front.

1. Why is `<3)` not getting replaced?
2. Why is `>:(` replaced by the code for `:(` when `>:(` is above `:(`
   in the object?

```js
//-------------------------------------------------
// Replace emoticons with images
//-------------------------------------------------

$(document).ready(function() {
    var emoticons = [
        { "code" : /:\)/ , "img" : "smile.svg" },
        { "code" : /;\)/ , "img" : "wink.svg" },
        { "code" : /:\*/ , "img" : "kiss.svg" },
        { "code" : /:\// , "img" : "unsure.svg" },
        { "code" : /:'\(/ , "img" : "cry.svg" },
        { "code" : /:p/ , "img" : "tongue.svg" },
        { "code" : /:D/ , "img" : "grin.svg" },
        { "code" : />:\(/ , "img" : "grumpy.svg" },
        { "code" : /:o/ , "img" : "astonished.svg" },
        { "code" : /:O/ , "img" : "afraid.svg" },
        { "code" : /8-\)/ , "img" : "nerd.svg" },
        { "code" : /8\)/ , "img" : "sunglasses" },
        { "code" : /:@/ , "img" : "angry.svg" },
        { "code" : /:\(/ , "img" : "frowny.svg" },
        { "code" : /<3\)/ , "img" : "love.svg" },
        { "code" : /:s/ , "img" : "confused.svg" },
        { "code" : /-_-/ , "img" : "dejected.svg" },
        { "code" : /\^\^/ , "img" : "laugh.svg" },
        { "code" : /:\|/ , "img" : "big_eyes.svg" },
        { "code" : /:x/  , "img" : "silent.svg" }
    ];

    $("#text-editor__box").on("keyup", function () {
        var element = document.getElementById("text-editor__box");
        var content = $("#text-editor__box")[0].innerHTML;

        for (var i = 0; i < emoticons.length; i++) {
            if(content.match(emoticons[i]["code"])) {
                $("#text-editor__box")[0].innerHTML = content.replace(emoticons[i]["code"], emoticons[i]["img"]);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```css
div { border: 1px solid; min-height: 1.2em }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contenteditable id="text-editor__box"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that you are not reading plain text, but HTML (via `innerHTML`), and in HTML a literal `<` is encoded as `&lt;`. Similarly `>` is `&gt;`.

The solution is to *read* the content with the `textContent` property instead:

```
    var content = $("#text-editor__box")[0].textContent;
```

Or why not using jQuery to the full:

```
    var content = $("#text-editor__box").text();
```

The second problem occurs because you keep working with the same `content` value, even after having made a change to the `innerHTML` of the element. So only the *last* match will determine the final assignment to `innerHTML`.

You can solve this by first making all the changes to the `content` string, and only update the `innerHTML` after the loop:

```
$("#text-editor__box").on("keyup", function () {
    var content = $("#text-editor__box").text(),
        changed = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < emoticons.length; i++) {
        if(content.match(emoticons[i]["code"])) {
            content = content.replace(emoticons[i]["code"], emoticons[i]["img"]);
            changed = true;
        }
    }
    if (changed) $("#text-editor__box").html(content);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! That solves the problem with the <3) emoticon. But the >:( emoticon is still replaced by the :( emoticon.

Comment: @Rajohan, I added an explanation for that as well.

Comment: Thanks! i solved it by adding a break; in the if statement. But, your solution would work as well thanks!

Comment: Just be mindful of cases where users may paste a whole phrase full of such emoticons in one go: you'll want to replace all of them, not just the first (and break).

Comment: That is true, your solution is better then.